# Masking HTML component's data

Tags: html, masking, data-masking

Is there a way where I can mask the data of any HTML component like date-picker component? As in Flex we can set masked attribute to true and the component's data gets asterisked.

Comment: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: thanks Vincent, will try this.

Answer (score 1):

There are many jQuery plugins out there for this. [Inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) is my favourite here is a [demo](http://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/).

[jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) is another popular one

Answer (score 0):

With CSS, you can mask what you want in HTML.

Check display: none; or visibility: hidden; 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: I dont want to hide the input component but want the data to be masked or dotted as in type password

Comment: Yes but password type only works for text input, I want this feature for all other components like dropdowns, grid data and all.

Answer (score 0):

Html 5 supports hidden inputs with type='hidden'